# Signed generated APK does not work the same as inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, apk, signed

I have generated an APK using Android Studio and I don't know why the APK behavior is different from installing the software using the usb wire on debug mode. I have two activities in the same application and when I install it from debug, it appears the first of them but if I install it using the APK, it is launched directly in the second activity.

Any hint?

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the new manifest after modifying it accordingly to the answer given by Bala Raja. However, the problem is that now Android is not identifying the second activity as a Launcher. What could I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.test"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/happy" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".Configure"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Show manifest please, if you have different for debug and release show both

Comment: paste the gradle file here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

paste this in your activity in manifest file which you want first.

Comment: That was it!! thanks. I have put both as main (copy-paste problems) and that's why I was having that behavior (strange it wasn't happen on Android Studio).

Comment: Ok.... I've seen why I needed to have the second activity as Main too. The second activity it's itself a launcher. If I don't mark it as Main, I don't know why, but it's not identified as a launcher...